# Arrow icon of menu Item does not rotate in shinydashboardPlus

Tags: shiny, shinydashboard, shinydashboardplus

The menu item arrow does not rotate when using shinydashboardPlus::dashboardPage() function while working in shinydashboard::dashboardPage() function.
Please see the two codes below:

```
library(shiny)
library(shinydashboard)
library(shinydashboardPlus)

header <- shinydashboard::dashboardHeader()

sidebar <- shinydashboard::dashboardSidebar(
  sidebarMenu(
    sidebarMenu(
      id = "tabs",
      menuItem("Charts", icon = icon("bar-chart-o"),
               menuSubItem("Sub-item 1", tabName = "subitem1"),
               menuSubItem("Sub-item 2", tabName = "subitem2")),
      menuItem("Widgets", icon = icon("th"), tabName = "widgets", 
               menuSubItem("Sub-item 3", tabName = "subitem3"),
               menuSubItem("Sub-item 4", tabName = "subitem4"))
    )
  )
)

body <- shinydashboard::dashboardBody()

shinyApp(
  ui = shinydashboard::dashboardPage(header, sidebar, body),
  server = function(input, output) { }
)
```

second code:

```
library(shiny)
library(shinydashboard)
library(shinydashboardPlus)

header <- shinydashboard::dashboardHeader()

sidebar <- shinydashboard::dashboardSidebar(
  sidebarMenu(
    id = "tabs",
    menuItem("Charts", icon = icon("bar-chart-o"),
             menuSubItem("Sub-item 1", tabName = "subitem1"),
             menuSubItem("Sub-item 2", tabName = "subitem2")),
    menuItem("Widgets", icon = icon("th"), tabName = "widgets", 
             menuSubItem("Sub-item 3", tabName = "subitem3"),
             menuSubItem("Sub-item 4", tabName = "subitem4"))
  )
)

body <- shinydashboard::dashboardBody()

shinyApp(
  ui = shinydashboardPlus::dashboardPage(header, sidebar, body),
  server = function(input, output) { }
)
```

How can I fix this issue? Please help! Thank you so much

Comment: It works fine for me.  Please restart your RStudio.

Comment: After double clicking, the arrow does not rotate.